# Python module "keyboard" works on Windows, not found on Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to use module `keyboard` in `Python 3.5.3`.

`pip`, `import` and my program work fine on `Windows`. On my Raspberry `pip install` works and `pip list` shows `keyboard`.

However when I try to run
`import keyboard` 
I get the error:
    "ImportError: No module named 'keyboard'"

I even tried to use `sudo import` as the keyboard documentation suggests with the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of Python?

Comment: Yes, the Pi has Python 2 & 3. I am using 3.

Comment: I also found that the keyboard module does not work with remote access using VNC. That made it useless for me. I am using Tkinter which is a prettier interface and works both locally and remotely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check which interpreter your `pip` is installing packages to.

You have both `Python2` and `Python3` installed on your PI, so only one of these will have access to the packages you are installing with `pip`.

You can check which interpreter your `pip` is installing packages to by running the following commands:

```
[root@pi] python2 -m pip list
[root@pi] python3 -m pip list
```

If `pip` is installing the packages to your `Python2` installation, you will need to explicitly call the `Python3` interpreter when installing the packages

```
[root@pi] python3 -m pip install keyboard
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Python 3.7.3 on Raspberry Pi, now the import keyboard is not longer required, just comment it or remove the line; all must works fine.